# Is it possible to validate date from param is less than date to param in Grape API (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

If I have the following params setup in a Grape API endpoint, is there a way to validate that `:date_from` is less than `:date_to`?

```rb
params do
  requires :date_from, type: Date,
                       description: "The date from in YYYY-MM-DD format",
                       coerce_with: Date.method(:iso8601),
                       allow_blank: false
  requires :date_to, type: Date,
                      description: "The date to in YYYY-MM-DD format",
                      coerce_with: Date.method(:iso8601),
                      allow_blank: false
end
```

I can probably do something in an `after_validation` block but curious to see if there is a way to do it using Grape's standard validations, which doesn't seem the case looking at the [docs](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#parameter-validation-and-coercion).

Comment: I don't remember built-in validators that would allow this, but you can create your own custom ones quite easily - do you consider this option?

Comment: Have a look at Grape's [`SameAsValidator`](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/master/lib/grape/validations/validators/same_as_validator.rb) – you can easily turn that into a `LessThanValidator`.

Comment: Looking at the SameAsValidator is a good shout @Stefan, will look at that